# Which combination of words sounds natural?

Tags: colloquial-language

I wonder which construction / combination is the most natural and colloquial (please mention your area when answering the question) and which is outright unnatural and wrong?

> There is a **store /shop** **at / on** the corner of the street; there is a photo in the
> corner of the **store / shop**; you can distinguish me at the desk **at the lesson
> in the classroom / in class / during a lesson in the classroom**.

Comment: Any prior research or explaination of why this is difficult for you in particular?

Comment: @JamesK yeah, I've done some, but regarding some of the parts of the construction there are some discrepant accounts. Some people  on forums say that you can use any of them in certain contexts, so I'd like to see which constructions seem best in the given context.

Comment: _Shop_ = UK usage. _Store_ = US usage. _At the lesson_ seems unnatural to me (UK).

Comment: The use of **distinguish**, while legitimate, is also unusual. I would expect a native English speaker to say **see/recognise me**. One wonders who has compiled the test?

Comment: @RonaldSole Russians.